# Find the smallest natural number using Chinese Remainder Theorem

Tags: elementary-number-theory, chinese-remainder-theorem

Question is find the smallest natural number $x$ such that,

\begin{align}
x &\equiv 1 \pmod 2 \\
x &\equiv 2 \pmod 3 \\
x &\equiv 3 \pmod 4\\
x &\equiv 4 \pmod 5\\
x &\equiv 5 \pmod 6\\
x &\equiv 6 \pmod 7\\
x &\equiv 7 \pmod 8\\
x &\equiv 8 \pmod 9\\
x &\equiv 9 \pmod {10}\\
x &\equiv 10 \pmod {11}\\
x &\equiv 11 \pmod {12}\\
x &\equiv 0 \pmod {13}\\
\end{align}

However when I use the proof of Chinese remainder theorem, I cannot even get over the first step where I must find inverse modulo: $$b_1 \frac{6227020800}{2}\equiv 1 \pmod 2$$ which I presume is $$0\cdot \frac{6227020800}{2} + 2\cdot 1 \equiv 1$$ hence 0?

I am somewhat confused. A friend did it using another method, but I would like to learn how to use the Chinese remainder theorem.

$$x\equiv a_1 b_1 \frac{M}{m_1} + \cdots + a_k b_k \frac{M}{m_k} \pmod M$$

Comment: Hint: $\ x\equiv -1\,$ mod $\,2,3,\ldots, 12\ $ iff their lcm divides $\,x+1\ \ $

Comment: "However when I use the proof of theorem, I cannot even get over the first step where I must find inverse modulo: $\frac M{m_1}=\frac{6227020800}2$"  Could you write out *what* proof and why exactly you are finding it?  It's not clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: @fleablood http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChineseRemainderTheorem.html

Comment: I know what the CRT theorem is.  I'm asking *YOU* to explain why you are doing that as the first step and why.

Comment: @fleablood So that I can find inverse modulo $b_i$ , in order to plug in to the equation...$x\equiv a_1 b_1 \frac{M}{m_1} + ... + a_k b_k \frac{M}{m_k}(mod\ M),$

Comment: @BillDubuque right, I thought that -1 works as well, but question asks for natural number

Comment: $-1\pmod 8*9*5*7*11$ and $0 \pmod 13$ so solve that.  If you get a negative number just add $8*9*5*7*11*13$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Chinese remainder theorem is about relatively prime modulos.  Having all the modulos from $2$ to $13$ is redundant.

$x\equiv 1 \mod 2; x \equiv 3\mod 4; x\equiv 7\mod 8$ are redundant and can be replaced with just $x \equiv 7 \pmod 8$.

Assuming the question is legitimate, we need not consider any $x \equiv j \pmod {2^km}$ and have to consider only $x\equiv l\pmod m$

i.e., this question can be reduced to.

$x\equiv 7\pmod 8$

$x \equiv 8\pmod 9$

$x \equiv 4 \pmod 5$

$x \equiv 6\pmod 7$

$x \equiv 10 \pmod {11}$

$x \equiv 0 \pmod {13}$.

All the rest are redundant, as the solution to the above is unique.

Note the solution to all but $x \equiv 0 \pmod {13}$ is $x \equiv -1 \pmod n$ for $n = 8,9,5,7,11$ so

$x\equiv -1 \pmod{8*9*5*7*11=27720}$ and $x \equiv 0 \pmod {13}$.

So you need to solve.  $x = 27720k -1 = 13m$

$27720 \equiv 4 \pmod {13}$

So $x \equiv 27720k - 1\equiv 0 \pmod {13}$

$\equiv 4k -1 \equiv 0 \pmod {13}$

So $4k \equiv 1 \pmod {13}$ so we just have to find the inverse of $4 \mod {13}$

And $4 \times 10 = 40 \equiv 1 \pmod{13}$ and so $k = 10$

and $x \equiv 277199 \pmod {27720*13}$

Comment: God, I feel like an absolute moron... thanks.

Answer (score 1):

$2,3,\ldots,12\mid x+1\iff  27720\mid x+1$ since $27720$ is the lcm of the divisors.

So $\, 13n = x  = 27720\,\color{#c00} k - 1\ $ so $\bmod 13\!:\,\ \color{#c00} k\equiv \dfrac{1}{27720}\equiv\dfrac{ -12}4\equiv -3\equiv \color{#c00}{10}$

hence $\, x = 22720(\color{#c00}{10}+13m)-1 = 277199 + 13\cdot 27720\,m$